# IOS 8 Simulator unable to boot

Tags: ios-simulator, runtime-error, xcode6

When I try to run my app with Xcode 6 Beta 4 on the Simulator iOS 8.0 I always get this error:

> Unable to boot the iOS Simulator

Actually I found some similar questions on this site and I tried all the answers and I still couldn't solve it. I had the same error with the Beta 2 version of Xcode 6 so I decided to wait. But now this is not normal anymore. Did anyone find a reason why this is happening and found the solution?

[image]

Comment: Try this :
Already answered here and tested to be working fine.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24998383/6665075

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am very happy that finally my issue resolved. Thanks to apple who helped me.

For those who are still looking for solution, here is the one which helped me:

Just unset DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES environment variable in the /etc/launchd.conf or ~/.launchd.conf  file. Which you can edit by `sudo vi /etc/launchd.conf` command. remove the above flag save it by "ZZ" (captial Z) and reboot the system. It works like a charm.

For reference: [Xcode 6 simulator, unable to boot error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210480/xcode-6-simulator-unable-to-boot-error/).

Comment: I think solution is more important rather than focusing on ZZ. I have provided more information for users who are new to terminal app.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora : where is /etc folder located? After searching in spotlight it is located in 'XAMPP' folder.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey: It is hidden folder on the hard drive where OS is installed.

Answer (score 12):

I found that removing and re-adding the simulator in Xcode 6 fixes the issue.

1. After opening xcode 6 open iOS simulator
2. Open hardware manage devices
3. Remove all the simulators and re-add them

[image: After opening xcode 6 open iOS simulator]
[image: Open hardware manage devices]
[image: Remove all the simulators and re-add them]

Comment: I wonder which part of this made it work?! And also, where the logs are that might give more clues to help analyse the underlying problem. Still – okay now, thanks!

Comment: You can open the devices screen in xcode from Window -> Devices

Answer (score 6):

Steps that I had to take to get this working.

1. Remove all versions of Xcode (I had 5 and 6 both in my Applications folder)
2. Install Xcode 6
3. Open Xcode and go to Xcode > Preferences > Locations
4. At the bottom of that screen under Command Line Tools, select Xcode 6.0 and make sure that the path under the select box reads /Applications/Xcode.app
5. Close that window and go to Xcode > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator
6. If the simulator has an error message, go to Hardware > Device > Manage Devices
7. Select each of the devices in the left hand column and delete them (delete key on the keyboard)
8. Completely quit out of the simulator and Xcode.  Shut down and restart your computer (not logout)
9. Once restarted, open up xCode, open the simulator, go back to manage devices and add back in the ones that you want.

The simulator should now work as expected!  Long winded, but that's the only way that I could get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to select Edit scheme

[image: Edit scheme]

Then select "Run" and change "Executable" from "Ask on Launch" to my own app.

[image: Select run]

The simulator menu in Xcode was then repopulated.

Answer (score 2):

I did follow most of the advices here without any simulators working. 
I had to remove a single simulator to get them working again.

```
prompt> xcrun simctl list
== Device Types ==
iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
iPhone 6 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus)
iPhone 6 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6)
iPad 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2)
iPad Retina (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina)
iPad Air (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air)
Resizable iPhone (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone)
Resizable iPad (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad)
== Runtimes ==
iOS 7.0 (7.0 - Unknown) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-0) (unavailable, runtime path not found)
iOS 7.1 (7.1 - Unknown) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-1) (unavailable, runtime path not found)
iOS 8.1 (8.1 - 12B411) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-1)
== Devices ==
-- iOS 7.0 --
-- iOS 7.1 --
-- iOS 8.1 --
    iPhone 4s (5F44F3AD-FE17-4EF6-A8DD-5A10E2EDCA09) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 5 (76053A14-F43C-4A32-8A72-96177C848741) (Creating)
    iPhone 5s (7998167A-E763-42F6-8945-65B514378154) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6 Plus (4360DA62-2C1E-4529-AA30-F11CC9357854) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6 (EE992AE3-B08E-4897-B28D-CEA486062E05) (Shutdown)
    iPad 2 (0D28BB5D-DD40-419D-8BA7-E9A1E9C777C6) (Shutdown)
    iPad Retina (365413A3-3F93-4EC4-B2DE-0D65358A81F3) (Shutdown)
    iPad Air (13CCAAF0-268D-47B0-9031-2034BE919BC1) (Shutdown)
    Resizable iPhone (8D5A265E-B714-4298-988C-3365E18391C9) (Shutdown)
    Resizable iPad (0EBB1D3B-951C-4BB1-813B-A0E83E67B0EB) (Shutdown)
prompt>
```

Solution was to delete the simulator stuck in (Creating) mode

```
prompt> xcrun simctl delete 76053A14-F43C-4A32-8A72-96177C848741
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps for solved above issue:

1. Search launchd.conf file in your mac
2. If not found then create from Terminal with help of command

~ user$ sudo touch /etc/launchd.conf

3. Terminal will ask you machine password
4. Then Open created file with help of command for EDIT, if terminal give you error as permission failed

~ user$ sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /etc/launchd.conf

5. Open file manually from /etc/launchd.conf (Shift+cmd+g) and enter /etc/ (TextEdit software)
6. In file "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES" flag replace with "ZZ" and save it.
7. Restart your machine.
8. Xcode will defiantly works.

Comment: thanx for steps out answere

Answer (score 0):

Even I encounter same problem, after a bit of toying around with Xcode and iOS simulator I am able to fix this issue with following steps:

- First I will try to Reset Content and Settings... in OS Simulator.
- If it doesn't work I will quit iOS Simulator and try.
- Still if it doesn't work I will quit both Xcode and iOS Simulator.

You should be able to fix things using above steps, if it doesn't, try reboot and then see if you can get things up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrestled with this problem for a while and running this line finally fixed it for me in Xcode 6.2, running iOS8.2.

```
launchctl setenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES ZZ
```

It is doing the same thing as the accepted answer, but I could no longer set variables with launchd.conf in Yosemite:

[Setting environment variables via launchd.conf no longer works in OS X Yosemite/El Capitan/macOS Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite)

Comment: A `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` custom environment variable sometimes means that you have adware in your machine. Beware if this worked for you, see here for more info: http://www.macissues.com/2014/04/23/how-to-detect-and-remove-genieo-for-mac/. Besides, the proper way of doing that would be `launchctl unsetenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`, rather than setting a wrong value like `ZZ`.

Answer (score 0):

I have both 6.3 and 6.2 for some older swift tutorials, most of the time it is fine but sometimes I get this error when switching and it seems like it is some background issue with the simulator. I just restart my system and it works fine after boot. Kind of the hard way to go around but I dont do this often.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue for Xcode 8 and 7.3.1 version. 
Upgrading **mac OX Sierra** solved the issue