# unable to boot the ios simulator XCode 6 iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

0, and trying to run my project on simulator
but it is showing error message unable to boot the ios simulator

after that my XCode is giving error message says 
An error was encountered while running (Domain = DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain, Code = 2)

I had search in google like hell but no luck

here what I tried are

I un installed and installed my Xcode 7 times :( No luck

### I restarted simulator and XCode many times no luck

Closed Xcode and iOS Simulator (and all related applications)

Install (or reinstall) Xcode6.0to Applications folder (direct from the .dmg file)

Open Xcode6.0 go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools and select "Xcode 6.0" (I am sure that I've selected the one in Applications folder)

Launch the iOS Simulator and go to iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...

Close all the applications and restart your mac (I unchecked "Reopen windows...")

Open Xcode6.0and test the iOS Simulator

### Still NO luck :( :( :( :(

I also followed each and every comments of following tutorials

[IOS 8 Simulator unable to boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952817/ios-8-simulator-unable-to-boot)

[Unable to run app in Simulator : Xcode beta 6 iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033417/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-beta-6-ios-8)

[Error opening iOS Simulator with iOS 8 beta version: "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023029/error-opening-ios-simulator-with-ios-8-beta-version-unable-to-boot-the-ios-sim)

### I am using  Mavericks OS X

Comment: This question is duplicated but for this question there is no right answer
I am trying to find the answer

Comment: I found the answer my self

Comment: can u share your answer plz?

Comment: May be it is Xcode issue
when i insatled Xcode 6.1 beta it was giving clear error says iOS 8 simulator not installed 

I tried many ways but no luck

finally I changed my mac there it is working fine


really this is the problem with apple they will never mention this kind of issues any where literally I fed up in this issue for over a week