# Xcode 6 simulator ,unable to boot error

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6, boot

I have installed latest Xcode 6 and try to run my project on iOS 8 simulator.It gives error as "unable to boot iOS simulator".
  I have tried all stack overflow answers but not able to fix this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to boot iOS 8 Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987302/unable-to-boot-ios-8-simulator)

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue and finally it is resolved. Thanks to apple who helped me.

For those who are still looking for solution, here is the one which helped me:

Just unset DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES environment variable in the /etc/launchd.conf or ~/.launchd.conf file. Which you can edit by "sudo vi /etc/launchd.conf" command. remove the above flag save it by using "ZZ" (captial Z) command and reboot the system. It works like a charm. Hope this helps you all.

Comment: Don't replace it with "ZZ" ... there's not really a reason to do that.  Just delete /etc/launchd.conf and reboot.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia : I suggested to save it after removing the flag DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES because there might be possibility of having other environment variables set in the launchd.conf file.

Comment: Yes, if that is the case, saving after deleting the line is appropriate, but there's no reason to replace it with "ZZ".  Also note that launchd.conf isn't supported any more as of OS X Yosemite, so it's probably easier for most users in this situation to just delete the file.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia: I have not asked to replace it with ZZ. I have given shortcut that how to save the file if it is editing using VI command from terminal. Edited the answer for more details.

Comment: Correct, sorry.  It was the other answer that says 'In "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES" flag replace with "ZZ" and save it.'  I should have added my comment to that one.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia yes. Np :)

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora: launchd.conf no such file exists. How is it?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey: Can you check the steps given by amol in below answer?

Comment: It does not work for me. I am using XCode 7.3.1 on MAC OSX EL Capitan. launchd.conf is empty, still i am facing "unable to boot simulator" error. Is there any other way to fix this isssue.

Comment: I too face same issue and can't able to proceed. Even though reinstalled Xcode in different locations. Surjeet can you please tell me what you did to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Following are the steps for solved above issue:

1. Search launchd.conf file in your mac
2. If not found then create from Terminal with help of command

   ~ user$ sudo touch /etc/launchd.conf
3. Terminal will ask you machine password
4. Then Open created file with help of command for EDIT, if terminal give you error as permission failed

   ~ user$ sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /etc/launchd.conf
5. Then open file manually from /etc/launchd.conf  (Shift+cmd+g) and enter /etc/ (TextEdit software)
6. Remove the "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES" line and save the file.
7. Restart your machine.
8. Xcode should work.

Comment: How can you find "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES" in a file you just created?

Comment: It does not work for me. I am using XCode 7.3.1 on MAC OSX EL Capitan. launchd.conf is empty, still i am facing "unable to boot simulator" error. Is there any other way to fix this isssue.

Comment: For me also. I am using EI Capitan 10.11.6 and with Xcode 7.3.1. I have tried all the stack overflow answers but none of them works out for me. I have tried reinstall Xcode in different location with with Xcode version but still no luck. launched.conf file is empty.