# How to download iOS 8 simulator Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6.1

I have installed Xcode 6.1. When I try to run application on iPhone 6/6+ it shows an error **'Unable to boot device in surest state : Creating'** and for 6+ it states **'Lost connection to iPhone 6 plus'**. I think this is an issue with simulator. I tried to download simulator for the same but only simulator for iOS 7 is available as shown in screenshot. **How do I install simulator for iOS 8**?

[image: Screenshot for issue]

Comment: Try with this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210480/xcode-6-simulator-unable-to-boot-error/26210496#26210496

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora : 'Launchd.conf' no such file found on Mac. How is it?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS 8.0 simulator runtime is not supported on Xcode 6.1 or later.  It is not expected to be available for download.