# Xcode throws error "Unable to boot iOS Simulator"

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6.1

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1. I can't start the iOS Simulator; it throws the error "Unable to boot iOS Simulator".

I tried resetting the simulator, reinstalling Xcode and my restarting MacBook. Nothing worked.

Finally I tried to unset the DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES ([IOS 8 Simulator unable to boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952817/ios-8-simulator-unable-to-boot)). But when I try to open the launchd.conf file, it shows a permissions error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run app in Simulator : Xcode beta 6 iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033417/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-beta-6-ios-8), 
[Error opening iOS Simulator with iOS 8 beta version: “Unable to boot the iOS Simulator”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023029/error-opening-ios-simulator-with-ios-8-beta-version-unable-to-boot-the-ios-sim), and probably a few more.

Comment: those answers doesnot work for me..I tried to reset the "DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES" flag, but I could open the launchd.conf file as it says file permission error.

Comment: Then you should explain what you tried and how the other answers didn't work for you in your question. Help us help you.