# Xcode 6 and iOS 7.1 simulator: Unable to boot the iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

The *iOS 7.1* simulator stopped working some time ago. I always get the dreaded `Unable to boot iOS simulator` error. The *iOS 8.3* simulator works.

I have gone through all the related answers, and have tried all this to no avail:

- Deleting *Xcode.app* and installing it again from the app store.
- Deleting all simulator devices and recreating them from `Window -> Devices`.
- Manually deleting the 7.1 simulator runtime from `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` and reinstalling through the preferences pane.
- Manually deleting all simulator Content and Settings from `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`.
- Making sure a `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment variable is not set.
- Making sure the correct *Command Line Tools* options is set in the preferences pane.

all sprinkled with restarts.

I don't know what else to do, sort of completely reinstalling OS X, which I'd prefer to avoid. This is using Xcode 6.3.2 (6D2105) on Yosemite 10.10.4 (14E36b).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try this @Ricardo Sánchez-Sáez : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29309957/4145420

Comment: That solution only works for people who has some adware being load through `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`. I don't have any `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment variable, so that doesn't work for me. (Besides, although that answer may work for people that has this adware, the proper way of doing that would be `launchctl unsetenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`).

Answer (score 3):

For people having the "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator" issue while running Xcode 6.x and who've upgraded to OS X 10.11 El Capitan, be warned that there is no effective solution as the iOS 7 simulator is functionally incompatible with El Cap.

See the following Apple Developer forum thread and read the response by jeremyhu:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5612

"This is a specific incompatibility of the iOS 7.1 libxpc being too old to satisfy the needs of the host's libsystem_stats.dylib."

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me and fixed it.

Run the following commands in order in Terminal.  I'm not sure what's causing it but I have to run it every so often to fix it.

sudo mkdir /private/tmp
sudo chmod 0777 /private/tmp

Comment: how to redo this? i did the same, now i can't see simulator