# Simulator not able to boot

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, boot

I tried all the possible solutions like reinstalling Xcode,reinstalled simulators and reset their configurations. Installed different versions of Xcode like Version 6,7,8. Still it throws error as unable to boot up simulator.
Bug report is saying that,

```
Time Awake Since Boot: 1200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   launchd_sim                     0x0000000103f9dfee 0x103f76000 + 163822
1   launchd_sim                     0x0000000103f7adc4 0x103f76000 + 19908
2   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000104384145 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
```

Binary Images:
       0x103f76000 -        0x103faefff +launchd_sim (2.1.0 - 560.20.11)  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/sbin/launchd_sim

```
External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 697
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
```

kindly help us with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS 8 Simulator unable to boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952817/ios-8-simulator-unable-to-boot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error opening iOS Simulator with iOS 8 beta version: "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023029/error-opening-ios-simulator-with-ios-8-beta-version-unable-to-boot-the-ios-sim)

Comment: ~/.launchd.conf file. I tried to get this file but not able to found. I tried using terminal same error occur. Please help in that.